# Python: POST request not working?

Tags: python, curl, firebase, python-requests

Making a simple POST request to Firebase. For some reason, it's not working. cURL with the same data is working, no issues. Any ideas?

Code below:

```
import requests    
r = requests.post("https://testapp-f55e1.firebaseio.com/test.json", data={"location":{"altitude":"200","latitude":"23.2", "longitude":"44.32"},"polution":{"pm10":"11","pm2":"123"}})
logging.debug(r)
```

It starts to work, but nothing happens.

```
INFO:Posting to https://testapp-f55e1.firebaseio.com/test.json
```

The request doesn't reach Firebase.

If I do a curl request with the same URL, it works like a charm. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: @TristanT, probably the  400 response would be a good inclination.

Comment: I look at the Firebase DB, and no new records are added when I execute the script. New records do appear when I type the curl command though... @TristanT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It expects *json* so replace *data=* with *json=*, requests will call *json.dumps* and set the headers for you:

```
In [6]: import requests
   ...: r = requests.post("https://testapp-f55e1.firebaseio.com/test.json", json
   ...: ={"location":{"altitude":"200","latitude":"23.2", "longitude":"44.32"},"
   ...: polution":{"pm10":"11","pm2":"123"}})
   ...: print(r)
   ...: print(r.json())
   ...: 
<Response [200]>
{'name': '-KTpRAvBqP4Ra-FSXtKO'}
```

The output from using data= was giving you a clue:

```
In [7]: import requests
   ...: r = requests.post("https://testapp-f55e1.firebaseio.com/test.json", data
   ...: ={"location":{"altitude":"200","latitude":"23.2", "longitude":"44.32"},"
   ...: polution":{"pm10":"11","pm2":"123"}})
   ...: print(r)
   ...: print(r.json())
   ...: 
<Response [400]>
{'error': "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value. Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names."}
```

Comment: Yes, that did it!